# SVG animation in Safari: translate operations not support

Tags: svg, safari, css-animations

Consider this simple SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<style type="text/css">
    text {  font-size: 400%; }

    @keyframes basic {
        0%   { transform: translateY(-100px); opacity: 0; }
        100% { transform: translateY(100px);  opacity: 1; }
    }

    .basic  { animation: basic  1s linear infinite; }
</style>
    <title>SVG Animation using CSS: Bounce</title>

    <text class="basic" x="150" y="200">SVG</text>
    <text x="100" y="200">–</text>

</svg>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tsyrak/Lrgs7bt4/)

It animates just fine in Firefox and Chrome. In Safari, however, only the opacity property is animated, and only the first `translateY` (that of 0%) is taken into account. (*Tested in Safari version 10.0.3*)

Using the exact same CSS and applying them in an HTML document, to a `<p>` for example, the animations work fine everywhere, including Safari.

Does Safari not support animation of `translate` in SVG? And where can I check whether it's supported?

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not support animation of the `<text>` element! Wrapping the text inside a group fixes the issue:

```
<g class="basic">
  <text x="150" y="200">SVG</text>
</g>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsyrak/259hkusr/1/)

This does not answer the second question however, where can one check whether that property is animatable or not in theory, and in practice?